# Woocommerce api rest v2 signature dont match

Tags: java, api, woocommerce, signature

I'm trying to call api rest of woocommerce, here you can see my code to call it, I have the oauth nonce, timestamp, key and secret and generate signature. I get this error.

```
{"errors":[{"code":"woocommerce_api_authentication_error","message":"Firma incorrecta - No coindicen las firmas"}]}
```

English: incorrect signature, signatures do not match.

```
public class Woocommerce {

private static String key = "ck_c6f7ea09138c------";
private static String secret = "cs_ed5c525f563dff-----";

private static final String HMAC_SHA1 = "HmacSHA1";

private static final String ENC = "UTF-8";

private static Base64 base64 = new Base64();

private static String getSignature(String url, String params)
        throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        InvalidKeyException {

    StringBuilder base = new StringBuilder();
    base.append("GET&");
    base.append(url);
    base.append("&");
    base.append(params);
    System.out.println("creating signature..." + base);

    byte[] keyBytes = (secret + "&").getBytes(ENC);

    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, HMAC_SHA1);

    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA1);
    mac.init(key);

    return new String(base64.encode(mac.doFinal(base.toString().getBytes(
            ENC))), ENC).trim();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException,
        IOException, URISyntaxException, InvalidKeyException,
        NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    List<NameValuePair> qparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    // These params should ordered in key

    qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_consumer_key", key));
    qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_nonce", ""
            + (int) (Math.random() * 100000000)));
    qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_signature_method",
            "HMAC-SHA1"));
    qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_timestamp", ""
            + (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000)));

    // generate the oauth_signature

    String signature = getSignature(
            URLEncoder.encode("www.buhoplace.net", ENC),
            URLEncoder.encode(URLEncodedUtils.format(qparams, ENC), ENC));
    // add it to params list
    qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_signature", signature));

    // generate URI which lead to access_token and token_secret.
    URI uri = URIUtils.createURI("http", "www.buhoplace.net", -1,
            "/wc-api/v2/products", URLEncodedUtils.format(qparams, ENC),
            null);

    System.out.println("url llamada" + uri);

    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
    // output the response content.
    System.out.println("Resultado de la llamada");

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
        int len;
        byte[] tmp = new byte[2048];
        while ((len = instream.read(tmp)) != -1) {
            System.out.println(new String(tmp, 0, len, ENC));
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I wonder if you found a solution meanwhile and if you could share it? I've been struggling for 3 days now with a similar problem.

Comment: @goncaloGomes I shared the answer. Have a look at it.

Comment: Have you looked at the code in Gitlab?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer. Look at this fragment carefully in it there is a local website with woocommmerce. In this request api button gets the orders with this local site.
Dont break the sequence of signature parameters. Its appended in unique series to generate correct signature.

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
        private static final String CONSUMERKEY = "ck_cfaf32e212c68c7c66b9a8f43625af72";
        private static final String CONSUMERSECRET = "cs_814f422a33bc737d188cb6a05ea4897c";
        private static final String METHOD = "HMAC-SHA1";
        private static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.21/wordpress/wc-api/v2/orders";
        private static final String PARAMNAME_KEY = "oauth_consumer_key";
        private static final String PARAMNAME_SECRET = "oauth_consumer_secret";
        private static final String PARAMNAME_NONCE = "oauth_nonce";
        private static final String PARAMNAME_TIMESTAMP = "oauth_timestamp";
        private static final String PARAMNAME_SIGNATURE = "oauth_signature";
        private static final String PARAMNAME_SIGNATURE_METHOD = "oauth_signature_method";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        Button bRequest, bClear;
        TextView tvResponse;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            bRequest = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            bClear = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
            bRequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    new TestApi().execute();
                }
            });
            bClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    tvResponse.setText("");
                }
            });
            tvResponse = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(getArguments().getInt(
                    ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }

        public String getSignature() {
            ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
            names.add(PARAMNAME_KEY);
            names.add(PARAMNAME_TIMESTAMP);
            names.add(PARAMNAME_NONCE);
            names.add(PARAMNAME_SIGNATURE_METHOD);
            return null;
        }

        class TestApi extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
            ProgressDialog d;
            JSONParser jparser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject response;
            List<NameValuePair> parameters;

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 + "";
                String nonce =  (Math.random() * 100000000) + "";
                parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_consumer_key",
                        CONSUMERKEY));
                // parameters.add(new
                // BasicNameValuePair("oauth_consumer_secret",
                // CONSUMERSECRET));
                parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_timestamp",
                        timestamp));
                parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_nonce",
                        nonce));
                parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_signature_method",
                        "HMAC-SHA1"));
                String encoded_base_url = "GET&" + URLEncoder.encode(URL) + "&";
                Log.d("encoded url", encoded_base_url);
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                builder.append(PARAMNAME_KEY + "=" + CONSUMERKEY + "&");
                // builder.append(PARAMNAME_SECRET + "=" + CONSUMERSECRET +
                // "&");

                builder.append(PARAMNAME_NONCE + "="
                        + nonce + "&");

                builder.append(PARAMNAME_SIGNATURE_METHOD + "=" + METHOD + "&");
                builder.append(PARAMNAME_TIMESTAMP + "=" + timestamp);
                String str = builder.toString();
                str = URLEncoder.encode(str);
                Log.d("prepared string", str);
                String signature = encoded_base_url + str;
                String encoded = "";
                try {
                    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(METHOD);
                    byte[] key = CONSUMERSECRET.getBytes("utf-8");
                    SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, METHOD);
                    mac.init(secretKey);
                    byte[] signaturebytes = mac.doFinal(signature
                            .getBytes("utf-8"));
                    encoded = Base64.encodeToString(signaturebytes,
                            Base64.DEFAULT).trim();

                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.d("signature", encoded);
                parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PARAMNAME_SIGNATURE,
                        encoded));
                response = jparser.makeHttpRequest(
                        URL,
                        "GET", parameters);
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPreExecute();
                d = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                d.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                d.dismiss();
                tvResponse.setText(response.toString());
            }

        }
    }
```

The url should be the complete url of wordpress store.